# Word to describe a list of literature a person has read

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe a list of the literature (i.e. novels, plays, poetry) you've read over your lifetime? *Ex libris* evokes the same idea, but isn't truly the mot juste, as it implies ownership rather than perusal.

Comment: literary repertoire; personal reading list; my bookshelf

Comment: *Li**s**terature*

Answer (score 2):

**Granted, it’s a versatile term, but I think that “catalog” would meet your needs.**

> **Catalog** *noun*:
>
> **1**. a complete list of items, typically one in alphabetical or other systematic order, in particular.
>
> • a list of all the books or resources in a library.
>
> *synonyms*: directory, register, index, list, listing, record, archive, inventory
>
> "a library *catalog*"
>
> see, google.com [**catalog**](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=define+catalog&sa=X&ei=y-QJVezxOcOXNt77grAO&ved=0CCAQ_SowAA&biw=1067&bih=550)
>
> **Origin of CATALOG**
>
> Middle English *cathaloge*, *cateloge*, from Middle French *catalogue*, from Late Latin *catalogus*, from Greek *katalogos*, from *katalegein* to list, enumerate, from *kata*- + *legein* to gather, speak — more at *legend*
>
> First Known Use: 15th century
>
> See, Merriam-Webster [**catalog**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catalog)

Answer (score 0):

A few people seem to have coined the term **biblio-biography** to describe a list of books they've read (examples [here](http://mackinbooksinbloom.com/2012/06/14/my-biblio-biography/) and [here](http://earthsignmamawrites.blogspot.com/2009/11/book-two-biblio-biography.html)), although these seem to be lists of books that influenced them the most. I imagine you could tweak it to clearly mean a list of *all* the books someone has read by adding a qualifier: **complete biblio-biography**, **lifelong biblio-biography**, etc.